# error:attempt to read or write outside 'hd0'

Tags: grubrescue

I tried all the advise given about this issue from online:
set root...,set prefix...,insmod normal, but after this step it continues to say 'error: attempt to read outside of 'hd0'.
I have no idea what to do. Would someone please help me.
thanks

Comment: Please is best you tell us what you've tried so we don't repeat ourselves...

Comment: ok so using the ls command i found out that my filesystem in (hd0,msdos6)

Comment: then i did set root=(hd0,msdos6)

Comment: set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub

Comment: 'insmod normal' then 'normal'

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem after a fresh Ubuntu installation on a virtual drive - fixed it by...

1. Physically disconnecting all drives not part of the virtual drive I was installing Ubuntu on
2. wiping the contents of the virtual drive ([re]initialized it in the raid controller GUI)
3. Completed the Ubuntu installation, shut down the machine, removed installation media
4. It booted into Ubuntu like normal and I was able to physically reconnect all drives without adverse effects :)

Hope this helps someone out there